# Unity Container - Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

im using unity container in my project and im trying to register the container to it self like this :

```
UnityContainer.RegisterInstance(UnityContainer);
```

But im getting the following exception :

```
Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
```

I tried searching the exception but all I found was related to mutex.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: UnityContainer.RegisterInsance(UnityContaier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container already registers itself (as `IUnityContainer`), so you don't have to register it. Consider the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer m_UnityContainer;

    public MyClass(IUnityContainer unity_container)
    {
        m_UnityContainer = unity_container;
    }
}
```

Now if you simply resolve this class as follows, it will have the container injected into it.

```
var obj = container.Resolve<MyClass>();
```

Please note that having your classes depend on the container means that you want to use the container to locate services and this [is considered an anti-pattern](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/object-composability-another-reason-why.html).

Comment: Thanks, after debugging I see that you are I dont need to register it, thats awesome thanks man.

Comment: While it's true that he didn't need to register the container to itself, this is not the answer to his question. Be it a good answer, it's useless to anyone seeking help with the question in the title.